# Connect to plain socket from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, sockets, networking, server

I have a Java back end  to connect to JavaScript Clients.

But i do not want to use WebSockets. My question is whether there is anything like plain socket connection like other languages like Java, Python, etc. in JavaScript.

Here is an example :

**Server.java**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server{
    public static boolean isRunning;
    public static ServerSocket server;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            isRunning = true;
            server = new  ServerSocket(3080);
            int id =  0;
            System.out.println("Server startes on port " + 3080 + " waiting for clients.");
            while(isRunning){
                Socket client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("New Client ID : " + (++id));
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Handler(id, client));
                thread.start();
            }
        }catch(SocketException se){
            System.out.println("Server has been Shutdown");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Handler implements Runnable{
    private int id;
    private Socket client;

    public Handler(int id, Socket client){
        this.id = id;
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            String s = "";
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                s = sc.nextLine();
                if(s.equals("HELLO")){
                    System.out.println("Hello from client " + id);
                }else if(s.equals("EXIT")){
                    System.out.println("Shutdown order from client " + id);
                    Server.server.close();
                    client.close();
                    break;
                }else if(s.equals("REPLY")){
                    System.out.println("Reply order from client " + id);
                    ps.println("Hello this is a reply from server!\nThank you for connecting!\nDONE");
                    ps.flush();
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Message from client " + id + " -> " + s);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        Socket client = new Socket("192.168.0.5", 3080);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Sending Hello to Server.");
        ps.println("HELLO");
        ps.flush();
        System.out.println("Sending Message to Server.");
        ps.println("Some Random Message");
        ps.flush();
        System.out.println("Sending Reply order to Server.");
        ps.println("REPLY");
        ps.flush();
        System.out.println("Reply from Server : ");
        String s ="";
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            s= sc.nextLine();
            if(s.equals("DONE"))
                break;
            System.out.println(s);  
        }
        System.out.println("End of Server's Reply.");
        System.out.println("Sending Shutdown order to Server.");
        ps.println("EXIT");
        ps.flush();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want the client to be JavaScript (From Browser).

I am not quite sure how to achieve it?

Comment: `anything like plain socket connection`.. what exactly do you think WebSockets are?

Comment: @ChloeAnderson: *"what exactly do you think WebSockets are"* - Websockets are not plain sockets. They are a HTTP request upgraded and also have their own framing and masking on top of it TCP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yeah thats the problem for my not using web sockets

Comment: @ChloeAnderson WebSockets or Socket.io are not plain sockets they have their own protocol over a normal socket

Comment: If you want this to work in the browser, using WebSockets would be the way to go, Java has WebSocket libs that look simply.  There is also WebRTC but that's more useful for peer to peer networking, eg.  If you was making a video conference app.  But again you still need to go via HTTP.  Also worth pointing out, webSockets give you security for free, over HTTPS.

Comment: @Keith as for now i am least concerned with security and efficiency i am only looking for the easiest solution as this is just a very small part of the project